# Nuxt how to access the exception error on the server error page?

Tags: nuxt.js

In Nuxt.js, is there a way to globally handle any server-side errors?

I'd like to conditionally redirect to my own Vue error page. For example:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   redirect("/error?message=the-error-message-here");
} else {
   // render the default server error page with the stack trace
}
```

Is this possible?

I've read about creating an `app/views/error.html` but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think that this can answer your question : https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-dev/

Answer (score 0):

you should put error.vue in here

*layouts/error.vue*

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
        <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>
        <NuxtLink to="/">Home page</NuxtLink>
      </div>
    </template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['error'],
    layout: 'error' // you can set a custom layout for the error page
  }
</script>
```

You must see this layout as a component displayed when an error occurs (404, 500, etc.). Similar to other page components, you can set a custom layout for the error page as well in the usual way.

here is the documentation :
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views#error-page